# Why my MX records doesn't refresh on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mx-record

I'm added mx record to cloud dns tab on Google cloud platform.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhZ89.png)

But when I check my mx records on www.digwebinterface.com there are not any mx record. Check [here](https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=xn--rjykatsomo-p5a.fi%0D%0A&type=MX&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=) my mx records.
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agJdJ.png)

What is wrong here?

[I added MX record to Google cloud platform (Picture of Google cloud platform mx record)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhZ89.png)

[I am waited many days, but MX record doesn't refresh (Picture of www.digwebinterface.com)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agJdJ.png)

(Sorry for bad English)

Comment: This does not appear to be programming related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to remove the @ in your MX record since it is no necessary in Google Cloud DNS.

Comment: That's worked for me. Thanks a lot!!!! I have this problem a loooong time!

Comment: I spent two days resolving this issue. I removed @ from the MX record, and it worked for me.